# Django DeleteView doesn't delete the object from data

Tags: python, html, mysql, django, sql-delete

I've just learned CreateView UpdateView and DeleteView models and then I got all of them working. I can change my object I can delete them, but after deleting an object I try to create another and creates one like the before hasn't been deleted. giving me the following pk of the deleted before

it still creates de object although the pk at the moment should be 3, I think after I click the delete button and confirm delete it isn't deleting from data.

These are my models:

```py
from django.db import models from django.urls import reverse

class Dreams (models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    objetivo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    imagem = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse ('webdeve:index', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titulo + ' - ' + self.objetivo


class Which (models.Model):
    lets = models.ForeignKey(Dreams, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    make = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    it = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.make
```

my views.py:

```
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .models import Dreams, Which
from django.urls import reverse_lazy


class IndexView (generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Dreams.objects.all()

class DetailView (generic.DetailView):
    model = Dreams
    template_name = 'detail.html'

class DreamCreate (CreateView):
    model = Dreams
    fields = ['titulo', 'objetivo', 'imagem']
    template_name = 'dreams_form.html'


class DreamUpdate (UpdateView):
    model = Dreams
    fields = ['titulo', 'objetivo', 'imagem']
    template_name = 'dreams_form.html'

class DreamDelete (DeleteView):
    model = Dreams
    template_name= ('dreams_confirm_delete.html')
    success_url= reverse_lazy('webdeve:index')
```

my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from webdeve import views

app_name = 'webdeve'

# Dreams

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),

# Dreams/detail

    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),

# Dreams/detail/add
    url(r'^dream/add/$', views.DreamCreate.as_view(), name='dream-add'),

# Dreams/detail/Update

    url(r'^dream/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DreamUpdate.as_view(), name='dreams-uptdate'),
# Dreams/detail/detete

    url(r'^dream/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$', views.DreamDelete.as_view(), name='dreams-delete'),

]
```

And my index.html with delete button:

```
<!-- linkando css no html -->
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block nav %}

      <ul>
        {% for Dreams in object_list %}
            <a href="{% url 'webdeve:detail' Dreams.id %}"><img src={{ Dreams.imagem }}></a>
            <li><a href="{% url 'webdeve:detail' Dreams.id %}"> {{ Dreams.titulo }} - {{ Dreams.objetivo }} </a><li>

            <!--delete BUTTON-->

              <form action="{% url 'webdeve:dreams-delete' Dreams.id %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="hidden" name="dreams_id" value="{{ Dreams.id }}" method="post" style="display: inline" >
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                </button>
              </form>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DeleteView` only deletes your object on POST, not GET. As a result, you need to use `method="post"` in your form since GET would render this confirm_delete.html again.

```
<form method="post" action="">
...
</form>
```

If you can get into DeleteView on GET, `action=""` is all you need to POST.

Comment: the real problem is that on the url its gaving me de id like the ones that a i've deleted before havent been deleted

is that a problem for the future?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you don't use `method="post"`, your object is not going anywhere. Well, for another question, it's not likely that you will have the same id as before. What database are you using? I can't recall that django ever use the same `pk` at all.

Comment: yeah, without the method you can do this but gotta create a confirm_delete.html and i was trying to redirect to the same index page whitout confirm_template, and with your answer that was possible.
about the pk, is that right so? my url should show me a number like 14 or 15 after the firsts 2 i've created and have never deleted.